# Unable to Override View in Devise Security Extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am unable to override the default view for `Devise::PasswordExpiredController#show` that was introduced in the [Devise Security Extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension). So far I tried to create the new view in my app as `app/views/devise/password_expired/show.html.erb`, but when I fire up rails, the default view is still rendered. I also tried [this](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/pull/200) generator, but same result.

I also followed the answer to the below, but same result.
[devise_security_extension: edit the password/expired/show view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178406/devise-security-extension-edit-the-password-expired-show-view)

Interestingly, I'm able to override [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) views just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set `config.scoped_views` to `true` in your devise initializer